# On Kervaire and Milnor's paper, "Groups of homotopy spheres: 1" (surgery on 3-manifolds)

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, manifolds, surgery-theory

Kervaire and Milnor's paper "Groups of homotopy spheres: 1" in Annals,
is the condition "$k>1$" necessary in Lemma 6.3? If yes, why?
(I couldn't find any part requiring the condition in their progress to obtain the lemma.)

Lemma 6.3 is the following: 
Let $M$ be a framed $(k-1)$-connected manifold of dimension $2k+1$ with $k$ odd, $k>1$, such taht $H_k M$ is finite. Let $\chi(\varphi, F)$ be a framed modification of $M$ which replaces the element $\lambda\in H_k M$ of order $l>1$ by an element $\lambda_k' \in H_k M'$ of order $\pm l'$. If $l' \not\equiv 0 \mod l$ then it is possible to choose $(\alpha)\in \pi_k(SO_{k+1})$ so that the modification $\chi(\varphi_\alpha)$ can still be framed, and so that the group $H_k M'_\alpha$ is definitely smaller than $H_k M$.

In addition, please recommend good documents to study surgery on a map from a (3-)manifold (with boundary) to kill the kernel of $H_k(-)$.

Comment: All orientable 3-manifolds can be framed.  So your question appears to be about whether or not certain types of surgeries lower the order of $H_1$,  provided $H_1$ started off finite.  This is a direct computation.  What difficulties are you having with the problem?

Comment: @RyanBudney The lemma also says that if $l' \not\equiv 0 \mod l$ then a surgery killing $\lambda$ reduces the order of (torsion of) $H_1$, doesn't it? Do you mean it holds for $k=1$, too?

Comment: It seems that their progress towards the Lemma uses Lemma 5.6. Does that lemma require $k>1$? (By the way, I don't know why people are voting to close the question, it seems reasonable to me in its current form.)